# django : how to confirm registration without email verification

Tags: django, email, registration, config, verification

I wnat to confirm registration without email verification 
How can it config?

And, Where is the django-registration views?
Can I change the registration views?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey there! Could you please explain in more detail what you would like to see happen? What's your desired outcome? More importantly: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) to make users register with their social account (which has been verified already). This would have the added bonus of being much quicker to sign up via.

You can [see the registration views here](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/fad7080fe769/registration/views.py). If you want to change them, copy the urls from django-registration's `urls.py` and put them into your own `urls.py`, then link them to a new `views.py` file and wrap the registration views with your own custom code.

Answer (score 1):

Django-registration comes with a default backend as well as a simple backend.
The default backend takes care of the email verification / activation.

If you want to disable the email verification in django-registration, then you'd need to use the simple backend instead.

Add something like the following to your urls.py:

`(r'^registration/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),`

Answer (score 0):

i would  use [janrain](http://www.janrain.com/) or [gigya](http://www.gigya.com/), i think janrain is better, it's just my opinion.

anyway what that would do is let people login using facebook, gmail, twitter etc..  like the django social auth...i'm just giving you other options :)